# post_submitbox_misc_actions not work with wordpress v5.5

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am try to create the buttons under Document in post/pages backend in wordress
Before wp v5.5 it was working but now it is not display those buttons. Not sure what the exact issue

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'my_post_submitbox_misc_actions',10, 1);

function my_post_submitbox_misc_actions($post){
    ?>
    <div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last my-options">
        <label for="my_custom_post_action">My Option</label><br />
        <select id="my_custom_post_action" name="my_custom_post_action">
            <option value="1">First Option goes here</option>
            <option value="2">Second Option goes here</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I have create these using the new babel method using react js and enqueue in using 'enqueue_block_editor_assets'  action then all set and its works doing some code things